# Touchpad isnt working in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: mouse, touchpad, 19.04, chromebook

I am running Ubuntu on a HP Chromebook 11 G5 Touchscreen edition.

uname -a:
Linux emattpoyourebooted-Setzer 5.0.0-15-generic #16-Ubuntu SMP Mon May 6 17:41:33 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

xinput:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/8vFdsy947G/

synclient outputs 
Couldn’t find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?

Device list: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/XRQ4Z7cG74/

I need help with the touchpad. It is way too hard to navigate without my touchpad.

Edit: sh won’t let me add the /sys/bus/serio/devices/serio0/protocol file. That file doesn’t exist in the filesystem. I tried as root to do the command but it won’t let me.

Edit #2: X recognizes the touchpad

Answer (score 0):

I encountered same problem, I was struggling for about past ten days or so.

Following fixed it for me:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo -n "elantech"> /sys/bus/serio/devices/serio1/protocol'
```

This command has to run at every reboot, as I noticed my scroll wasn't working, so I added it to cron (`sudo crontab -e`):

```
@reboot sudo sh -c 'echo -n "elantech"> /sys/bus/serio/devices/serio1/protocol'
```

Then run `sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub` and add following line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="psmouse.elantech_smbus=0"
```

Save the file & update grub using `sudo update-grub`.

That's it.